# Merges's folder's content keeps getting deleted with Cordova rm platform command

Tags: ios, cordova, merge, platform

If I run "Cordova platform rm iOS" command through terminal, Cordova CLI is also removing iOS folder from merges directory. Phonegap's documentation says that Platform-specific web assets (HTML, CSS and JavaScript files) are contained within appropriate subfolders in merges directory.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed as part of  3.3.1-0.2.0 merge to master branch Cordova CLI:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/pull/118

In order to get latest version of cordova CLI , please follow "Installing from Master" instructions on following URL:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli